# List's remove method is raw

Tags: java, collections

The question says it all..

From List's code:

Add method:
`public boolean add(E e) { ... }`

Whereas, remove method:
`public boolean remove(Object o) { .. }`

Is there any specific reason for this?

Answer (score 7):

From [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) :

> If this list does not contain the element, it is unchanged

So adding a type constraint here would be simply useless, while the constraint on `add` ensures at compile time the list contains what is written on the box.

Note that there is some liberty for implementation as the method is allowed to throw a

> ClassCastException if the type of the specified element is
>   incompatible with this list (optional)

The ArrayList implementation doesn't throw this exception :

```
439    public boolean remove(Object o) {
440         if (o == null) {
441             for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
442                 if (elementData[index] == null) {
443                     fastRemove(index);
444                     return true;
445                 }
446         } else {
447             for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
448                 if (o.equals(elementData[index])) {
449                     fastRemove(index);
450                     return true;
451                 }
452         }
453         return false;
454     }
```

This means you don't have to check the class of raw objects before you do the remove operation.

Comment: But this won't give any compile time error if we invoke this with wrong type. 
What I was doing was to remove an element if some array contains it.
Instead of doing `list.remove(array[i])` , I did `list.remove(array)` which I found out during runtime.

Comment: Depending on your list implementation, it might be totally legal to try to remove an object of the wrong type. This is "by design" and is sometimes useful (if you have raw objects to "remove" it means you don't have to check their class before you do the remove operation).

Comment: I am using plain ArrayList. But I thought generics were introduced to reduce this kind of errors.

Comment: There is no problem with an ArrayList : you can call remove with any Object. See edit.

Comment: Yes, but I want to be warned about type mismatch, just like add(). Also contains() is implemented the same way.

Comment: If *you* want this, you may simply make an ArrayList decorator. I see why you prefer the additional compile time check but you have to realize this would have meant reduced features, so I personally approve Sun's choice on this point. I say "personally" because it's really a matter of personal taste...